# Подключение js (symfony)

Tags: javascript, symfony

Подскажите, почему не отрабатывает скрипт app.js? А именно не выводится "console log" и "alert"? В консоли никаких ошибок нет.

Подключено на странице так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}" >
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
            <script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello DefaultController!</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css" >
            </head>
    <body>
            mainpage
                    <script src="/build/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Сам скрипт:

```js
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["app"],{

/***/ "./assets/css/css.scss":
/*!*****************************!*\
  !*** ./assets/css/css.scss ***!
  \*****************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin

/***/ }),

/***/ "./assets/js/js.js":
/*!*************************!*\
  !*** ./assets/js/js.js ***!
  \*************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */
// any CSS you require will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
__webpack_require__(/*! ../css/css.scss */ "./assets/css/css.scss"); // Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to require it.
// var $ = require('jquery');


console.log('Hello Webpack Encore! Edit me in assets/js/app.js');
alert("alert");

/***/ })

},[["./assets/js/js.js","runtime"]]]);
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался:

Подключил скрипты и стили так:

```
        {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
```